# TFS Adding a user which does not belong to our domain

Tags: tfs

We have a auditor who want to access to our TFS to view source codes in our company.

I am wondering if I need to create a user in the active directory to our domain and then assign this active directory user to TFS?

What would be the best way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to sit with the auditor and show them what they need to have access to. You should not give external folks access.

However, if you need to you will have to create an account in AD (local TFS) or AAD (VSO) for that person to get access.

Add that user with specific rights to what the auditor wants.